# What's the sci-fi collection that includes stories about Ball Inc, a James Bond-type agent, and a level 20 domain in the Congo?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I came across a book in the 1990s — itself probably dating to the '70s or '80s — called something along the lines of 6 Greatest/Best/Top Science Fiction stories. It was an unusual number — not the top 10 or top 5, but something along the lines of 6 or 7.

The collection contained a number of really original stories. In one, a secret agent featured pretty prominently, and although it was only a couple of pages long, there was a terrific twist.

In another, some form of bureaucrat had surreptitiously built himself a level-20 mansion in the Congo, above his pay grade, and was scared he'd be found out.

In third, a sleazy interactive porn video producer was trying for a new business venture, and was being financially blocked by a religious group that was calling itself Ball Inc.

Does anyone have any idea what the names/authors of these short stories are, or what the collection was called?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**I came across a book in the 1990s—itself probably dating to the '70s or '80s—**

[*Science Fiction Origins*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?29134), published in 1980, edited by [William F. Nolan](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?838) and [Martin H. Greenberg](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?509). As far as the [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi) knows, this is the only place your third story (["Malice in Wonderland"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59435)) has been published outside of its original appearance in [*If*, January 1954](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58738+c) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/1954-01_IF#page/n5/mode/2up)), and the only place your other two stories (["The Fasterfaster Affair"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?95473) and ["Hopper"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63468)) have ever appeared together.

**—called something along the lines of 6 Greatest/Best/Top Science Fiction stories. It was an unusual number—not the top 10 or top 5, but something along the lines of 6 or 7.**

The number 7 is not part of the title, but the fact that it contains seven stories is stated twice on the [front cover](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51WP9QXBWVL.jpg): "THE ORIGINAL STORIES ON WHICH SEVEN CLASSIC NOVELS WERE BASED" and "SEVEN MIND-STUNNING TALES OF TOMORROW BY THE GREATEST SCIENCE FICTION MASTERS OF OUR TIME . . ."

**The collection contained a number of really original stories. In one, a secret agent featured pretty prominently, and although it was only a couple of pages long, there was a terrific twist.**

["The Fasterfaster Affair"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?95473) by [William F. Nolan](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?838), later expanded into a novel called [*Space for Hire*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?15953). At 11 pages, it's by far the shortest story in this anthology; the rest are novelette or novella length. The secret agent is JamesTen:

> When JamesTen teleported into the office wearing his twin-tone perforated Venusian breathingboots and a rakishly cut sports jacket in worsted plastic, Miss Manypiggies sobbed brokenly and threw herself into his arms. "Rip off my clothing, James," she pleaded. "Love me, rape me, torture me, I don't care! Take my subtly tanned supple woman's body and—"
>
> JamesTen pushed her gently aside. "Not now, Manypiggies," he husked in a silken voice reserved for love-crazed secretaries. "Z wants me inside, where things count. God knows what's up in there, but it's my kind of trouble. Now, be a sweet and buzz me in, chop-chop."
>
> "Chop-chop," sighed Miss Manypiggies as JamesTen stepped lightly into the Matter Disintegrator. She thumbed the proper button and the suave secret agent wavered and vanished.
>
> He reappeared, all atoms neatly in place, beside Z's desk.
>
> "Good to see you, Ten," rumbled Z. His outwardly pleasant tone meant another joust with death was in the offing. JamesTen smiled thinly.

From the "Author's Afterword":

> Fleming's death, in 1964, failed to end the life of his creation—and Bond is still seen today, in fabulous new screen adventures. But what, I asked myself, would happen to a *robot* version of 007 in the far world of the future? Might be fun to write about one.
>
> Early in 1965 I signed a contract to edit an all-android anthology, [*The Pseudo-People*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?248450), set to include some original fiction. As editor Nolan I assigned writer Nolan (as Frank Anmar) to conjure up a new tale for the book, and this robot version of Bond (called JamesTen) was the rather insane result. I pitted my superagent against a cosmic fiend who was intent on the destruction of the entire universe, a superthreat worthy of a super-Bond. I had absolutely no plans for expanding any part of the story into a novel. In fact, when I drafted "The Fasterfaster Affair" in March, 1965, I was still six months away from the completion of my first novel, [*Logan's Run*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run).

**In another, some form of bureaucrat had surreptitiously built himself a level-20 mansion in the Congo, above his pay grade, and was scared he'd be found out.**

["Hopper"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63468) by [Robert Silverberg](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?54), a novelette originally published in [*Infinity Science Fiction*, October 1956](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?108121), later expanded into a novel called [*The Time Hoppers*](http://majipoor.com/work.php?id=1174).

> Quellen's offense was a unique one. No one else, to his knowledge, had been shrewd enough to find a way out of heavily-overpopulated Appalachia, the octopus of a city that spread all over the eastern half of North America. Of all the two hundred million inhabitants of Appalachia, only Joseph Quellen CrimeSec had been clever enough to find a bit of unknown and unsettled land in the heart of Africa and build himself a second home there. He had the standard Class Thirteen cubicle in Appalachia, plus a Class Twenty mansion beyond the dreams of most mortals, beside a murky stream in the Congo. It was nice, very nice, for a man whose soul rebelled at the insect-like existence in Appalachia.
>
> The only trouble was that it took money to keep people bribed. There were a few who had to know that Quellen was living luxuriously in Africa instead of dwelling in a ten-by-ten cubicle in Northwest Appalachia, like a good Thirteen. Someone—Brogg, he was sure—had sold out to Koll. And Quellen was on thin ice indeed.

**In third, a sleazy interactive porn video producer was trying for a new business venture, and was being financially blocked by a religious group that was calling itself Ball Inc.**

["Malice in Wonderland"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59435) by [Evan Hunter](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1716), later expanded into a novel called *Tomorrow and Tomorrow* or [*Tomorrow's World*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?20217). The protagonist, Van Brant, is a multimedia pornographic literary agent:

> "I have compiled a list of alleged literary agents who are today soliciting the majority of smut on the market. You, unfortunately, are one of the chief purveyors. I have been systematically eliminating these men, starting at the top and working my way to the bottom.
>
> **[. . .]**
>
> "Now, then. I've come to ask that you discontinue the submission of manuscripts to (a) the magazines, (b) the paperbacks, (c) the stereoscopic, the three-dimensional, and the sensory mediums."

The organization he's having trouble with is called Ball Associates. Here, he's having a problem with his drug supply:

> "Probably a small shortage. Maybe a shipment got fouled. Anyway, I want to ask you about the marketing setup. We usually get checks from Vizco and Young & Co. on Thursdays. There were none in this morning's mail. Any idea what's wrong?"
>
> "Yes. They've both been taken over by a new outfit."
>
> "Oh. What's the name of the new owner?"
>
> Lizbeth sucked in her breath.
>
> "Ball Associates," she said.

Comment: Well spotted! Will have to 2x check re: Malice in Wonderland, but from what I've read of the Tomorrow's World description, that's exactly it (I think you're right — it's a drug provider, but the new venture he's excited about is virtual porn). Been trying to find this for years, thanks!